# Choosing selecting one account sometimes and choosing multiple accounts sometimes on plaid

Tags: account, plaid

I can see that plaid allows configuring whether one account can be selected or multiple accounts can be selected via the account select configuration (https://plaid.com/docs/link/customization/#account-select), but does plaid support allowing one account to be selected vs multiple accounts to be selected based on some flag?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

As you mentioned, this setting is controlled by the account select configuration. The account select configuration itself is set up on a per-Link customization profile basis.

So, if you want to sometimes use account select in multi-select mode and sometimes use it in single-select mode, all you need to do is create two different Link customization profiles and associate one with multi-select and the other one with single-select. Then, when you call /link/token/create, specify which of the two customization profiles you want to use via the optional `link_customization_name` parameter.